# App Configuration service for on-prem dotnet core app

Tags: .net-core, azure-app-configuration

We have a dotnet core 3.1 console application. It is deployed to on-premise Windows server. There is some sensitive information that we would like to keep in Azure Key Vault. However, instead of accessing Key Vault directly, we would like to access it via App Configuration service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/solution-ideas/articles/appconfig-key-vault

Above article mentions that any application can use Azure App Configuration (under Potential use cases).

Does "any" include application hosted outside of Azure? If so, can you share high level steps on how to access App Configuration service from dotnet core app that is not running in Azure.

Comment: Pretty sure this only applies to Azure: they said *any application*, not *any platform*.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that any means any, looks like the steps remains the same as long as the connection string to config services work, i'll do some testing with quick start material and let you know..

Best!

Comment: Hi,  i've just finished the quick start sample for aspnetcore 5 under Windows 10 IIS on premise and it worked, as i said, nothing change on the implementation (Just took me a little bit effort to setup IIS for netcore 5), now i'll test the reference for console app on  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-dotnet-core , but, it seems to work as long as the program can access the configuration service. I let you know.

Best!

Comment: Yeah, it worked like a charm, no additional steps needed. Please let me know if you need the test projects to examine aspnetcore 5 and netcore 3.1 implementations made